# How to completely detect Proxies using PHP

Tags: php, proxy, fraud-prevention

I would like to fully detect proxies before someone enters to my website, to prevent fraudulent actions.

Is there any script in PHP which could actually detect all proxies, like Transparent, Anonymous, High Anonymous, Socks, Tor, etc?

I have a code but I'm not sure that it filters all proxies:

```
$proxy_headers = array(
        'HTTP_VIA',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED',
        'HTTP_CLIENT_IP',
        'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR_IP',
        'VIA',
        'X_FORWARDED_FOR',
        'FORWARDED_FOR',
        'X_FORWARDED',
        'FORWARDED',
        'CLIENT_IP',
        'FORWARDED_FOR_IP',
        'HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION'
    );
    foreach($proxy_headers as $x){
        if (isset($_SERVER[$x])) die("You are using a proxy!");
    }
```

Can someone help me to create a complete solution which can stop ANY proxy traffic coming to my website?

Comment: Why would you want to block proxies? They aren't evil. Many people need to use proxies because there are some ... problems in their countries. Or maybe they just sit at work.

Comment: Have you searched? The headers don't filter all proxies, Tor for example doesn't send them. You'll need a black-list.

Comment: So only if I'll get a blacklist, then I'll be able to detect High anonymous proxies, tor, etc which doesn't send header? There is no other way?

Comment: This is more like identifying thieves with their ID card.

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to fully detect proxies before someone enters to my website, to prevent fraudulent actions.

This makes no sense at all. There are plenty of totally legitimate use cases for proxies. Also, a *malicious* proxy user can remove those headers, and any other indication that they might be using a proxy.

The only really secure way for you to detect a proxy user would be to have a list of all proxy IPs that exist.

I would call this off, and spend my time on building more useful security measures. One that may become useful over time is the ability to easily block certain IPs or even IP ranges used by troublemakers.